# Change Windows 10 Calendar default font size

Tags: windows-10, fonts, calendar

I'd greatly appreciate if someone told me how to make the font size on the Windows 10 Calendar app bigger. I followed the instructions in this link (changing the font in the Mail app) but it didn't work.

Is there any way?

Link to obsolete instructions:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/can-i-enlarge-the-text-entries-in-win-10-calendar/c4053610-1546-46e9-8f9c-e17fc629f609

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change calendar font size, But you can make the default font size
bigger in windows as shown in the screenshot The lower highlighted portion is for scaling which is sometimes useful as well (keep in mind that both of these options it will apply across the windows so not limited to calendar only)

[image: Settings]

Comment: That one I know, but I don't want my other Windows apps to get affected. This is such a major drawback. I hope this has been addressed in Windows 11.